# Df export all into one larger file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df reading in multiple .xlsx files. I have manipulated what I need in the files and the export view is exact. However, I need the data to export into one larger 2 column file rather than multiple individual files.

Any help is appreciated. I haven't been able to figure the problem out on my own.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

folder = input('Enter the folder name: ')

os.chdir('C:/Users/PCTR261010/Desktop/' + folder)
FileList = glob.glob('*.xlsx')

for fname in FileList:
    df = pd.read_excel(fname).assign(New=os.path.basename('mpcc_' + (fname.split('-', 1)[0]).split('@', 1)[1]))
    df1 = df[['New', '<ID>']]

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('ParttoMPCC_Import.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Import', index=False, header=False)
    writer.save()
```

Comment: Are you trying to append to the xlsx as opposed to overwrite it everytime?

Comment: seems like writing to csv would be easier

Comment: For user, they prefer .xlsx

Comment: @xyzjayne need to append, so it's probably to do with it being under the for loop

Comment: ````xlsxwriter```` doesn't support append. What's preventing you from combining the dataframes before writing the result to a file?

Comment: Instead of writing to excel in each iteration of your `for` loop could you create a list of DataFrames, append to the list with each iteration, call `pd.concat` to combine the DataFrames, and then write to Excel?

Comment: @vealkind. I tried pd.concat(df1) and it errored out.

Answer (score 0):

You can append desired columns in a single DataFrame and write that DataFrame to an excel file. Below code should do the job.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

folder = input('Enter the folder name: ')

os.chdir('C:/Users/PCTR261010/Desktop/' + folder)
FileList = glob.glob('*.xlsx')

df1 = pd.DataFrame()    # create an empty df
for fname in FileList:
    df = pd.read_excel(fname).assign(New=os.path.basename('mpcc_' + (fname.split('-', 1)[0]).split('@', 1)[1]))
    df1 = df1.append(df[['New', '<ID>']])    # append columns data to the df1

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('ParttoMPCC_Import.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Import', index=False, header=False)
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.concat` as follows:

```
data = []
for fname in FileList:
    df = pd.read_excel(fname).assign(New=os.path.basename('mpcc_' + (fname.split('-', 1)[0]).split('@', 1)[1]))
    df1 = df[['New', '<ID>']]
    data.append(df1)


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('ParttoMPCC_Import.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df = pd.concat(data)
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Import', index=False, header=False)
writer.save()
```